# Cannot inject @Test annotated Method with TestNG and JMockit

Tags: java, testng, jmockit

So basically, I want to check if test() function calls the static method `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a string.")`. This is what I have achieved so far.

**Libraries used:**

1. TestNG 7.4.0
2. JMockit 1.49

**Current Test code:**

```
package com.example;

import javax.swing.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import mockit.Mocked;
import mockit.Verifications;

public class Activity1Test {
    @Test
    public void shouldShowInputDialogOnUpdateTextButtonClick(@Mocked JOptionPane jOptionPane) {
        Activity1 activity1 = new Activity1();
        activity1.test();

        new Verifications() {{ JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a string."); }};
    }
}
```

**The test() function:**

```
public void test() {
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a string.");
}
```

Unfortunately, it gives me this error:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: TestSuite
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.781 s <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
com.example.Activity1Test.shouldShowInputDialogOnUpdateTextButtonClick  Time elapsed: 0.434 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.testng.TestNGException: 

Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [shouldShowInputDialogOnUpdateTextButtonClick] with [class javax.swing.JOptionPane].
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection
```

Answer (score 0):

That ought to work, but I've never used JMockit with TestNG.  In normal JMockit (with JUnit), you will get something like that if you've forgotten to include the --javaagent stuff jmockit requires when you run - verify that's in place.  However, based on the error you are getting, looks like testng is trying to handle the test-method-with-argument as a parameterized test (and it's aborting before jmockit can have a look at it).  I think testng also works with javaagents, in which case, the order of the agents might be reversed, not sure.

The simple fix...   Move the "@Mocked JOptionPane joptPane" from inside the parenthesis of this test method and make it an instance variable in this test class instead (out of the test and into the test-class).  That will mean your method no longer has parameters (TestNG won't complain) but at the downside that now that joptPane is mocked for every test in this test-class (perhaps that's ok).